# How to obtain a current user locale from Spring without passing it as a parameter to functions?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.1 and want to find the locale active for the current user is there a way to grab the locale directly without being forced to pass it from the controller to the service layer ... etc.

does spring store the locale in a thread local storage where it can be grabbed by calling some static method?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I was also looking for how to access the locale without passing the `Locale` around, but I'm still pretty new to Spring and found most solutions to be confusing. It turns out, though, that Spring MVC does store the locale in thread local storage. It can be accessed by:

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

> The last approach [...] is based on a thread local in order to provide the current locale in any entity of your architecture. [...] You must be aware that the content of the LocaleContextHolder corresponds by default to the locale specified within the Web request.

From: [Configuring locale switching with Spring MVC 3](http://templth.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/configuring-locale-switching-with-spring-mvc-3/). (That post also offers alternative configurations/methods for getting the locale, which might be useful for anyone looking to do this).

You can also view the `LocaleContextHolder` docs from Spring [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html).

Comment: Also worked for me, here is the method list of LocaleContextHolder
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html

Answer (score 5):

It depends on where you have configured to store the locale, in session or in cookie?

In my application I have configured to store the user locale in its session with below mentioned configuration.

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/labels</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/messages</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/include</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

If you have done somthing like this then you can easily retrieve the locale parameter from the session.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: Japs this does not help me because I want to know the Locale inside a service and I don't want to pass the Locale to the Service method, I want to be able to call a static function and get the current locale for the user as resolved by whatever locale resolver is in configured. Normally you can just define a parameter of type Locale to an Annotation controller and it gives the resolved the locale I just don't want to pus the locale parameter to lower layer I just want to get it from a thread locale.

Comment: In that case you can also get the localeResolver bean in your service as autowired and then you can call the class method to determine the current locale set by the user in session.

Comment: injecting the LocaleResolver does not work because the LocaleResolver requires acces to the httpServletRequest or Response so I would have to pass those down to the service layers, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: In that case there is no choice left but to get the locale in the controller and then pass that to the service as an argument. I don't see any other possibilities the way you want the locale.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same need, so came up with putting `Locale` into `ThreadLocal` context. We already had an object (some user information) stored in `ThreadLocal` context, so just appended it (looks like a hack, but the quickest solution we found).

Comment: This is exactly what [`LocaleContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html) does: Storing the `Locale` into a `ThreadLocal` variable. No need to use a custom hack (because Spring is already doing that hack for you).