# Why is LemonUtil.getMessage() isn't replacing the variables?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-lemon

In the signup process of Spring Lemon, I'm trying to send the verification email.
I've put **messages_en.properties** and **messages_fr.properties** in my `resources`folder.
Here is the relevant content of **messages_en.properties**

```
com.naturalprogrammer.spring.verifyEmail: Hi,<br/><br/>Your email id at XYZ is unverified. Please click the link below to get verified:<br/><br/>{0}<br/><br/>
```

But when I look at the logs, it sends the mail without replacing the **{0}** by the verifyLink.

I looked at the code and figured out that this portion of LemonService is the isse :

```
            // send the mail
        mailSender.send(user.getEmail(),
            LemonUtil.getMessage("com.naturalprogrammer.spring.verifySubject"),
            LemonUtil.getMessage(
                "com.naturalprogrammer.spring.verifyEmail", verifyLink));
```

But the actual work is being done by this code in LemonUtil.java :

```
                /**
 * Gets a message from messages.properties
 * 
 * @param messageKey    the key of the message
 * @param args          any arguments
 */
public static String getMessage(String messageKey, Object... args) {

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792551/how-to-obtain-a-current-user-locale-from-spring-without-passing-it-as-a-paramete
    return messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, args,
            LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

I managed to solve it somehow by deleting the {0} in the .properties, and by adding the link myself like this :

```
            // send the mail
        mailSender.send(user.getEmail(),
            LemonUtil.getMessage("com.naturalprogrammer.spring.verifySubject"),
            LemonUtil.getMessage(
                "com.naturalprogrammer.spring.verifyEmail", verifyLink) + verifyLink);
```

I think the **getMessage** method of **org.springframework.context.MessageSource** is not working properly.
My question is : what could prevent **messageSource** from working ?

Comment: Try putting ` ` (whitespace) around `{0}` ... Putting it between HTML tags could be problematic.

Comment: I tried that, no success

Comment: To get some answers, seems like you'd need to try it out with a minimal project, just with a single controller class with `MessageSource` injected, without involving Spring Lemon, and then re-post the question crisply.