# How to get Request and Locale in a Scheduled method with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I've created a scheduled method with Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
public void example(final HttpServletRequest request, final Locale locale) {}
```

I need the `request` and the `locale` parameter, but when I add these I get the error:

> Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled.

How can I bypass that problem to get the `request` and the `locale` objects in a scheduled method?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding `HttpServletRequest` you can try to inject the request, since it is request-scoped. For every request it will be different. About locale, you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792551/how-to-obtain-a-current-user-locale-from-spring-without-passing-it-as-a-paramete

Comment: How on earth would that work? The scheduled method runs in the background, without having a notion of a request. So no it won't work and as stated you can only use no-arg methods. What is it you are trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: @M.Deinum you're right, my bad... :D I wasn't even thinking about the context...

Comment: Well, I see... I've refactored my code in order to do without the response and locale objects. That's the right way... thanks @M.Deinum